# Jquery insert row after specific parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to insert a new row between two other existing rows in my html table using jquery and ajax call. In particular i need to insert the new row after the only one which contains an "a" element whose id value is "27".

This is my Html table:

```
<table class="table-list" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="90%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th width="15%">Categoria</th>
<th width="15%">Servizio</th>
<th width="15%">Operazioni</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>categoria1</td>
<td></td>
<td>
<a id="27" class="del" href="#">Delete</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>categoria2</td>
<td></td>
<td>
<a id="29" class="del" href="#">Delete</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This is the part of jquery code that doesn't work:

```
$("<tr><td>"*+response.categoria+*"</td><td>"*+response.nome+*"</td><td><a href='#' id='"+*response.row_id*+"' class='del'>Delete</a></a></td></tr>").insertAfter($("a[id='27']")).closest("tr");
```

(Where response.categoria = "categoria1",response.nome = test, response.row_id = 28)

This is what i get with my code: 
[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `*+response.categoria+*` — this is not valid JS.

Comment: @Terry I think he's trying to highlight that code.

Comment: Note that using `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` will not W3C validate your document cause redundant attributes. Use CSS instead.

Answer (score 1):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/cebawu/1/edit)**

To focus on your main issue, your jQuery line says in other words this:

```
$("SOMEHTML").insertAfter(  $("a[id='27']")  ).closest("tr");
```

you can see that after inserting it...  jQuery is than targeting a `.closest("tr")` doing nothing ***which will silently fail.***

Should be like: `.insertAfter( $("#27").closest("tr") );`

Note above that `a[id=]` is not needed since ID must be unique-per-page so there's no need to define the `a` anchor element and target it's Attribute property (which is also pretty slow.)

Not sure if you were trying to highlight your code markup example,
 **but your JS should look like:**

```
<td>"+ response.categoria +"</td>
```

without the `*`

Also in your JS you're closing twice the `</a></a>` which is wrong

**Here's the fixed code:**

```
var row = "<tr><td>"+response.categoria+"</td><td>"+response.nome+"</td><td><a href='#' id='"+response.row_id+"' class='del'>Delete</a></td></tr>";  
$("#27").closest("tr").after( row );
```

**Or using insertAfter if you like it better**

```
$("<tr><td>"+response.categoria+"</td><td>"+response.nome+"</td><td><a href='#' id='"+response.row_id+"' class='del'>Delete</a></td></tr>").insertAfter($("#27").closest("tr"));
```

- You have mal-formatted HTML (extra `</tr>` tags), which leads me to sugggest you a better code editor (that will highlight errors for you).
- Also Note that using `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` will not **W3C validate** your document cause redundant attributes. Use CSS instead

Comment: I think he's trying to highlight code, not literally have `*` in the code.

Comment: @Brad thanks but noisy (was already stated under the Q comments section). Give some answer-quality-buildup *grace-time* (more than 1min I mean) :)

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors in your code:

- Incorrect parenthesis wrapping after the `insertAfter()` method.
- Double `</a>` tags
- Extraneous `</tr>` tag in the third last line.

Also, one suggestion: `$('a[id="27"]')` is likely to be inefficient compared to just `$('#27')`. Since ID is unique, there is no need to conjugate it with the tag name (`a`) or use any attribute selector `[id=""]`.

I fixed your code, and now it appears to be working. See demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/0gLyrqso/

```
$("<tr><td>"+response.categoria+"</td><td>"+response.nome+"</td><td><a href='#' id='"+response.row_id+"' class='del'>Delete</a></td></tr>").insertAfter($("a[id='27']").closest("tr"));
```